# push viewController and keep the webView state ios

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, state, reusability

The first view of my app is HomeViewController which contain a webView.
From an other view in the app I want to navigate (or push) my HomeViewController and in the same time I want to keep the first state of the webView.

How can I store and reuse the webView content?

Other possibility would be to store the viewController state and re-use it again.
Any idea would be helpful?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to go back to HomeViewController from some other controller, you should not be using a push, since that will create a new instance, not go back to the original one. If you go back to the same instance, your web content should still be present.

Comment: Okay, and how we go back to the same instance of HomeViewController?

Comment: That depends on your app structure. You could use an unwind segue, which is the only kind that doesn't instantiate a new controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by doing this.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

class var instance: HomeViewController {

    struct Static {
        static var instance: HomeViewController?
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = HomeViewController()
    }
    return Static.instance!
    }
..............................

}
```

And when I want to push again my HomeViewController I do this:

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HomeViewController.instance, animated: true)
```

As simple as that.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. When I tried your code, I didn't get the same instance of HomeViewController, and I now had 3 controllers on the stack (Home --> VC --> Home). If you push to VC again, you'll have 4 controllers on the stack. Each time you do a push, you'll add another controller on the stack, and eventually you'll have a memory problem.

Comment: If you are getting the same instance, you need to add more information, because the code you posted here doesn't do that.

Comment: In fact I have a webView in my ViewController and the idea is to load it only one time.
The code works and I keep the same content of the viewController.
When doing this I agree with u that I'll increment the stack with new viewControllers, but I can't see other idea at the moment (maybe I will remove the old HomeViewController from the stack manually).

Comment: I said how to do it in my comment. Use an unwind segue.